# Shell Scripting - ¿Cómo analizar los caracteres de una oración ingresada por teclado?

Tags: linux, shell

Deseo saber cómo puedo analizar individualmente todos los caracteres de una palabra u oración ingresada por medio de teclado.

Ejemplo:

Ingresamos= Programación en shell script.

De dicha oración podemos saber que tenemos:

```
2 letras a
2 letras e
2 letras i
2 letras o
1 letra g
```

Y así sucesivamente, pero **¿Cómo se puede hacer esto por medio de código?**

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 4):

No soy experto en **`bash`**, pero aquí va mi solución

```
# script.sh

read -p "Ingresa un texto por favor:" texto

# Esta variable se usara para ir guardando los caracteres
# que ya han sido procesados y no volver a hacerlo si hay mas
# de una ocurrencia en el texto.
cache=""

# Arrancamos un loop ejecutando el comando read. Hay que notar el argument -n1,
# que lo que hace es que el comando read lea la cadena de a 1 (uno) caracter.
# prueba a poner -n2, y procesara en cada loop 2 caracteres a la vez.
while read -n1 letra; do

    # Revisamos si la letra actual esta presente en nuestra variable cache
    if [[ ! "$cache" =~ "$letra" ]]; then

        ocurr=($(echo $texto | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | grep $letra | wc -l))

        # Guardamos (concatenamos) la letra actual en la variable cache
        # para no volver a procesarla de nuevo.
        cache="$cache$letra"

        # Imprimimos en pantalla
        echo "$ocurr letras $letra"
    fi

done < <(echo -n "$texto")

# El bucle realmente comienza cuando pasamos a while a traves del comando echo
# el texto introducido. Aqui la direccion de flujo de entrada en invertida,
# usando el caracter <
```

Para ejecutarlo escribir **`bash script.sh`** en la terminal y [enter]

```
$ bash script.sh 
Ingresa un texto por favor: Que es shell?
1 letras Q
1 letras u
3 letras e
2 letras s
1 letras h
2 letras l
1 letras ?
```

La siguiente porción de código es la mas compleja. Primero debes saber que hace el caracter **`|`**. Se llama **`pipe`**, o tubo. Y lo que hace es recibir el output de un comando a la izquierda y lo pasa (input) al comando a la derecha.

```
echo $texto | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | grep $letra | wc -l
```

1. **`echo $texto`** genera un output stream para pasar el texto al siguiente comando.
2. **`sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'`** separa cada letra en multiple lineas y por cada una pasa al siguiente commando
3. **`grep $letra`** busca la letra actual (del bucle) por una ocurrencia.
4. **`wc -l`** cuenta la cantidad de veces que grep devolvió un letra (porque lo ha encontrado).

Ponerme a explicar cada comando detalladamente sería un engorro en un solo post, principalmente el comando **`sed`**. Que es una de las que menos he usado en mi vida. **(Como dije mas arriba no soy un experto en esto)**. Así que debes recurrir al MAN PAGE de cada comando y aprender mas por tu cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar AWK , te dejo información al respecto:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/how-to-count-the-number-of-a-specific-character-in-each-line

saludos.